# How to set remote_addr to the real client IP?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, x-forwarded-for

I have the following `nginx.conf` and in the `access.log` I am getting as `remote_addr` the same IP for every request, which is the IP of my VM.

```
events{}
# See blow link for Creating NGINX Plus and NGINX Configuration Files 
# https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/basic-functionality/managing-configuration-files/
http {

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # The identifier Backend is internal to nginx, and used to name this specific upstream
    upstream backend {
    # BACKEND_HOST is the internal DNS name used by the Backend Service inside the Kubernetes cluster 
    # or in the services list of the docker-compose. 
    server ${BACKEND_HOST}:${BACKEND_PORT};
    }

    server {
        listen ${NODE_PORT};
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api/ {
        resolver 127.0.0.11; 
        #nginx will not crash if host is not found    
        # The following statement will proxy traffic to the upstream
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }

}
```

However, I need to have in the `remote_addr` field the initial client IP. I know that I can use the variable `realip_remote_addr`, but I wanted to ask if there is any configuration that changes the `remote_addr`. Is somehow this possible?

EDIT: As I search more about that I think that it is important to mention that I use `docker-compose` to run the nginx as part of a frontend service. Maybe this is related to the network of docker.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is enough to add these two fields to the request header:

```
proxy_set_header x-real-ip $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

See the documentation at [proxy_set_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) for more details.

In your case:

```
server {
    listen ${NODE_PORT};
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        resolver 127.0.0.11; 
        #nginx will not crash if host is not found    
        # The following statement will proxy traffic to the upstream
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header x-real-ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work. I still get the IP of my VM in the remote_addr field of nginx access logs.

Comment: I think it is important to mention that nginx is part of a frontend service run with `docker-compose`, so it is inside a docker network.

Comment: Have the exact same issue, would you please have any update? adding the 2 headers does not change anything, as $remote_addr is still the Docker's IP.

Answer (score 1):

We have to understand the importance of the field `remote_addr`, it tell the application server where to respond back, if you overwrite this value than the server won't pass the response to the network interface it came from. So for this use case you want to log real client IP , please refer to the below snippet, it might help:

```
events{}
# See blow link for Creating NGINX Plus and NGINX Configuration Files 
# https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/basic-functionality/managing-configuration-files/
log_format  logs_requested  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$request_time" "$upstream_response_time" "$pipe" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

http {

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # The identifier Backend is internal to nginx, and used to name this specific upstream
    upstream backend {
    # BACKEND_HOST is the internal DNS name used by the Backend Service inside the Kubernetes cluster 
    # or in the services list of the docker-compose. 
    server ${BACKEND_HOST}:${BACKEND_PORT};
    }

    server {
        listen ${NODE_PORT};
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access_logs.log  logs_requested;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api/ {
        resolver 127.0.0.11; 
        #nginx will not crash if host is not found    
        # The following statement will proxy traffic to the upstream
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }

}
```

In above snippet `logs_requested` is the `log_format` that is defined according to one's requirement. Client IP information can be see in `http_x_forwarded_for` variable, and `access_log /var/log/nginx/access_logs.log  logs_requested` line is included in `server` block to log the request in this `logs_requested` format.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Nginx documentation on setting up your access log desired format
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/#access_log

Some more info:
https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/AddOns/released/NGINX/Setupv2